# Permanent redirection not working on hashtags - Htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have converted some php page into wordpress now am working on redirection, its works on all links expect following line. Its working but redirecting to wrong page.

Ex:

`www.example.com/parentpage-childpage#samplepage`

it should redirect to here

`www.example.com/parentpage/child-page/sample-page`

but its redirecting to

`www.example.com/parentpage/child-page#sample-page`

RedirectPermanent

```
/parentpage-childpage#samplepage /parentpage/child-page/sample-page
```

How to fix this. Thanks

Comment: Not possible. The url part after # doesn't get send to the server.

Comment: You can not redirect fregment `#` using htaccess  as `#` is not sent to the server. You need to use a client side redirect.

Answer (score 0):

[This page](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/Fragment/draft-bos-http-redirect-00.txt) from W3C explains that

> URIs may contain a fragment identifier, indicated by a # (hash mark)
>   in the URI[URI]. For example
>
> ```
>   http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names#NT-NCName
> ```
>
> A client that is retrieving this fragment will ask a server for the
>   resource "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names" and will then locate the
>   fragment "NT-NCName" in that resource.

So, the client will only request for the URI without the fragment identifier (after the hash). You won't be able to use URL rewritting with #, as it is not transmitted to the server.

Instead, you could use JS on client side to handle this problem.